# How to use 'add_value_provider_argument' to initialise runtime parameter?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Take the official document 'Creating Templates' as an example:
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/creating-templates

```
class WordcountOptions(PipelineOptions):
@classmethod
def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
  # Use add_value_provider_argument for arguments to be templatable
  # Use add_argument as usual for non-templatable arguments
  parser.add_value_provider_argument(
      '--input',
      default='gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt',
      help='Path of the file to read from')
  parser.add_argument(
      '--output',
      required=True,
      help='Output file to write results to.')

pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(['--output', 'some/output_path'])
p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
wordcount_options = pipeline_options.view_as(WordcountOptions)
lines = p | 'read' >> ReadFromText(wordcount_options.input)
```

`wordcount_options.input` is a RuntimeValueProvider. I want to use the value specified at runtime(executing the template), so I need to use `wordcount_options.input.value`. However, it does not have attribute 'value' when creating the template. It only has 'default_value' instead. I try to specify a value when creating the template(so that I can use it now and later), but no mater what value I specify at runtime, it only use the previous value that I specified when creating the template.

(Basically, my input is a pickle file so I can not use `wordcount_options.input` directly.)

Comment: How are you passing the runtime value to the template? Can you share that code block?

Answer (score 2):

Just below the linked example is a section [Using ValueProvider in your functions](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/creating-templates#using-valueprovider-in-your-pipeline-options).

The documentation shows using the `.get()` method on the `ValueProvider` parameter to retrieve the runtime value.

Note that the value cannot be used during pipeline construction, since it hasn't been injected from the template. You should only call `ValueProvider.get()` inside of runtime methods such as `DoFn.process()`.